# Se puede poner un limite en un auto_increment?

Tags: mysql

Me gustaria saber si existe alguna manera de poner un rango en un id auto incrementable en mysql.
Por ejemplo:

Que solo se puedan añadir ids desde 1200 hasta 1500, y que cuando se añada un id 1501, este no se agregue porque ha llegado al limite.

Se que se puede cambiar el valor de inicio de un auto_incremente con el codigo

`ALTER TABLE nombreTabla AUTO_INCREMENT=1200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tbl_new` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=2200000000;
```

Puedes usar `auto_increment` al final

---

Por defecto, el valor de `auto_increment` es 2.1 Billones

Pasado dicho valor, la base de datos obtendrá errores al tratar de insertar nuevos registros

---

Además si usas un lenguaje de programación (PHP, Python, Perl, etc) (lo más probable) para insertar registros en la base de datos, puedes contar el número de filas en la cuenta, y si es mayor al número deseado, arrojar un mensaje diciendo que se ha llegado al límite

---

Basado en tu comentario: Puedes hacer que `id` no pase de 4 dígitos poniendo `INT(4)`

Ejemplo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `mi_table` (
    `id` INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY_KEY(`id`)
)
```

Con esto harás que la base de datos no admita números mayores a 4 dígitos en `id`

---

Con PHP, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db_name");
$max = 1500; // Los registros de ID no pasarán de este número
$comprobar = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM mi_tabla");

if (mysqli_num_rows($comprobar) >= $max) {
    die("Se ha alcanzado el límite");
} else {
   // Código aquí
}
```

**Explico un poco**

Primero, conectaremos al base de datos con `mysqli_connect`, además seleccionaremos TODOS los registros de la tabla en la base de datos y comprobaremos si el número es mayor o igual al número máximo que definimos en la variable `$max` y si es mayor mostraremos un mensaje

Comment: En mi caso, ocupo que los valores no pasen de 4 digitos, es decir, 1200-1500 o de 2500-3500, ya que son para facturas y en mi país los unicos digitos que cambian en las facturas son los ultimos 4

Comment: Exacto, trabajo con PHP, como podria realizar esa validación en PHP?

Comment: Muchas gracias colega, definitivamente me has ayudado :D